# Quien tiene mas dinero?

Tags: java

Desarrollando un problema de tare, debo determinar quien tiene mas dinero. Actualmente tengo 2 errores, si agrego  for (int i=0;i<5;i++) me imprime 5 veces el resultado (que es erroneo) si lo elimino me imprime quien tiene mas dinero aunque no sea cierto.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
int montojuan1 = 0, montojuan2 = 0, montojuan3 = 0, montopedro1 = 0, montopedro2 = 0, juan = 0, pedro = 0;
juan = (montojuan1 + montojuan2 + montojuan3);
pedro = (montopedro1 + montopedro2);

   System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 1 de monedas que tiene Juan:");
   montojuan1= leer.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 2 de monedas que tiene Juan:");
   montojuan2= leer.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 3 de monedas que tiene Juan:");
   montojuan3= leer.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 1 de monedas que tiene Pedro:");
   montopedro1= leer.nextInt();
   System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 2 de monedas que tiene Pedro:");
   montopedro2= leer.nextInt();
   for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
       
       if (juan > pedro)
           
        System.out.println("Juan tiene más dinero");
    else
        System.out.println("Pedro tiene más dinero");
  }
}
```

En consola imprime:

```
run:
Ingresa cantidad 1 de monedas que tiene Juan:
1
Ingresa cantidad 2 de monedas que tiene Juan:
1
Ingresa cantidad 3 de monedas que tiene Juan:
2
Ingresa cantidad 1 de monedas que tiene Pedro:
2
Ingresa cantidad 2 de monedas que tiene Pedro:
1
Pedro tiene más dinero
Pedro tiene más dinero
Pedro tiene más dinero
Pedro tiene más dinero
Pedro tiene más dinero
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Si las variables `juan` y `pedro` no cambian nunca de valor y siempre las inicializas a cero, la condición `juan > pedro` siempre será falsa porque tanto `juan` como `pedro` valen `0`. Lo puedes meter en un bucle o donde quieras, pero siempre valdrán `0` si no les das nunca valor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El orden de las instrucciones están mal, primeramente deberías leer o almacenar los datos luego guardar la suma total de ambas personas y finalmente comparar quien tiene mas, saludos

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Inicializando las variables
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int montojuan1 = 0, montojuan2 = 0, montojuan3 = 0, montopedro1 = 0, montopedro2 = 0, juan = 0, pedro = 0;
        //Almacenando datos
        System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 1 de monedas que tiene Juan:");
        montojuan1= leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 2 de monedas que tiene Juan:");
        montojuan2= leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 3 de monedas que tiene Juan:");
        montojuan3= leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 1 de monedas que tiene Pedro:");
        montopedro1= leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Ingresa cantidad 2 de monedas que tiene Pedro:");
        montopedro2= leer.nextInt();
        //Guardar total de monton ingresados
        juan = (montojuan1 + montojuan2 + montojuan3);
        pedro = (montopedro1 + montopedro2);
        //Determinar quien tiene mas dinero
        if (juan > pedro)
            System.out.println("Juan tiene más dinero");
        else
            System.out.println("Pedro tiene más dinero");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Noches el bucle for no es necesario. El orden de las operaciones esta mal.  adjunto las correcciones.

Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

int montojuan1 = 0, montojuan2 = 0, montojuan3 = 0, montopedro1 = 0, montopedro2 = 0, juan = 0, pedro = 0,montopedro3;

```
    System.out.println("JUAN");
    System.out.println("cantidad 1");
    montojuan1 = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cantidad  2 ");
    montojuan2 = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cantidad 3");
    montojuan3 = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("PEDRO");
    System.out.println("cantidad 1:");
    montopedro1 = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cantidad 2:");
    montopedro2 = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresa  3:");
    montopedro3 = leer.nextInt();

    //operacion de las 6 entradas
    juan = (montojuan1 + montojuan2 + montojuan3);
    pedro = (montopedro1 + montopedro2+montopedro3);
    
    
    //evalua el resultado de la operacion que se encuentra en la variable juan y pedro y verifica 
    //cual es el mayor:
    if (juan > pedro) {
        System.out.println("Juan tiene más dinero");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Pedro tiene más dinero");
    }
```